# Requiring unknown module "buffer" in react-native-route-flux

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I import react-native-route-flux and tried to run the application in genny motion emulator I got this kind of error even in the basic sample app that we create after react native init.

> Requiring unknown module "buffer"

`import { Router, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';`

This is what i have in package.json

```
    {
  "name": "HelloFlux",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.0.2",
    "react-native": "^0.26.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.22.23"
  }
}
```

The other day it was working fine.

Comment: Could you provide the full error log? Also please list what dependencies are contained in your package.json

Comment: I already encountered with same issue, and i resolved it by installing it from github npm i aksonov/react-native-router-flux --save
instead of npm. not that the latestest version on github is 3.22.23

Comment: will try to do it your way.   npm i aksonov/react-native-router-flux --save. 
I tried with  npm i react-native-router-flux --save

Comment: just dealing with this same problem, I'll report back when I solve it

Comment: There are some recent issues: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/697

Comment: `npm remove ...` , and then reinstall from github where a recent push fixed things: `npm install --save aksonov/react-native-router-flux`

Comment: actually, do this instead, as mentioned in the issues I linked to in the comments: `npm install --save assert@1.3.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://%20github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/697), there are some dependency issues with the `assert` lib.

Best solution for a fix, force an older version of the broken dep:

```
npm install --save assert@1.3.0
```

Another solution that worked for me (sorta), install from github:

```
npm install --save aksonov/react-native-router-flux
```