# How to upgrade react-native to latest version

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to upgrade to the latest version of react-native(react-native-0.26.2) so i can use react-native-flux-router.

I am getting this error:
[image: screenshoterror]

The chrome console only shows default error messages.

Here is my package.json file

```
      "dependencies": {
    "@remobile/react-native-splashscreen": "^1.0.3",
    "firebase": "^3.0.3",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.12.0",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.7",
    "q": "^1.4.1",
    "react": "15.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.26.2",
    "react-native-action-button": "^1.1.4",
    "react-native-android-statusbar": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-animatable": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-button": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.9.3",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.2.3",
    "react-native-file-uploader": "0.0.2",
    "react-native-gifted-spinner": "0.0.4",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.18.17",
    "react-native-keep-screen-on": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.4.2",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-orientation": "^1.16.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.26.5",
    "react-native-simple-store": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^2.0.2",
    "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.3",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "2.10.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "5.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "1.1.0-beta"
  }
```

Here is output from adb logcat

[logcat output](http://pastebin.com/raw/G17eqbH7)

Steps taken to upgrade:
Note* In order to get the current setup to work

> "react-native": "0.25.1",
>   "react": "0.14.5", 
>   "react-native-router-flux": "3.22.23"

I had to install this specific version of

> "assert": "1.3.0"

. Reason is I was getting a buffer exception and after searching this is what I found [solution to unknown module buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317282/requiring-unknown-module-buffer-in-react-native-route-flux)

When I tried to upgrade I got the latest version of react-native and react. I then downgraded the version of react after seeing the warning message that react-native requires

> "react": "15.0.2"

I then removed the assert package. I tried everything from uninstalling the app and re-compiling, I tried rebooting both the computer and the phone. The only thing I found from searching is this [search result](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/50)

So I even installed the latest version of babel globally, not sure that did much of anything though. I then also made sure I had something in the constructor in all the views.

```
 export default class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            foo: 'bar'
        }
    }
```

I am not sure what to do next because there is no useful errors in the console.

Comment: Can you list the steps you have taken so far in the upgrade process?

Comment: Sure thing. Will be in front of computer in about a hour

Comment: If possible, please share minimal code base where this error is reproducible.

Comment: thats the issue, i don't know what to put or how to guess where it is going wrong??? I am not sure if it is my code or if it is a 3rd party package I have installed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With React Native 0.26 and higher, React itself is no longer bundled with React Native. This error seems to be caused by a `propType` definition where your or a third party component tries to use `PropTypes.object`.

You need to either update the offending component or change your own to access `PropTypes` directly from the `react` package like this:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

class SomeComponent extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    someProp: PropTypes.object
  };
}
```

Comment: There is a script that does this for you if you've got a large number of files. Check it out [here](https://github.com/sibeliusseraphini/codemod-RN24-to-RN25) !