# react-native update to latest version

Tags: react-native

I am completely new to RN, just started couple of weeks ago learning about it.  I got react-native v.0.47 which was the latest at that time.

Now, I see there is a new version 0.48.  As a new guy, I have no experience with updating of react-native.  I have found similar question here on SO but it is old and related to version 0.26 ([How to upgrade react-native to latest version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37481998/how-to-upgrade-react-native-to-latest-version))

Since I am new, I would like to use latest and greatest but I am still concerned if my apps will still work.

How often do the updates happen?

How simple/difficult and how risky is to update?

Will my apps still work if I update?

How do I update react-native and how do I update my apps to use this latest version?

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the `react-native` documentation about version upgrading [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html). Upgrading usually causes no issues and your app will work properly but no one can guarantee that you won't face any problems so it's wise to use a version control system such as git just in case. That way if you face any serious problems you can revert your changes easily.